# How to communicate with a SAP application from JAVA

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, abap, netweaver, sap-xi

we are planning to integrate our Sales and Distribution module to SAP application. We need to store the Sales information in a SAP application.

we are migrating the existing data using `Exchange Infrastructure/ BDC` of SAP to load sales module existing data.

Now our challenge is how to continuously interact with SAP from JAVA to store and retrieve data from the sales module?

Is there any tools available to communicate with SAP from java.

Thanks,
Anil Kumar C

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have multiple options:

- use [SAP Business Connector](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_dm40/helpdata/en/6f/1bd5c2a85b11d6b28500508b5d5211/content.htm)
- use [SAP JCO](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04/helpdata/en/6f/1bd5c6a85b11d6b28500508b5d5211/content.htm) to call SAP RFC Functions from java
- create SOAP Webservices in SAP and consume them from java

I really recommend the webservices way.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend you to use JCO library to call RFC functions in SAP, it's the easiest way to fetch and store data in SAP from a programmer's perspective.

Webservices in enabled from ECC5 version, every function module can be wapped as a Webservice interface. However, it's hard to map and parse structures or internal tables in SAP as wsdl file. When you get a error on calling Webservices from sap, you will spend a lot of time to find the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

i know this question is really old, but maybe this might help someone out there so i post this.

i definetly recommend to have a look at ***Hibersap*** (http://hibersap.org/).
it's an opensource library that let's you declare the SAP-Functions you'd like to call using plain Java Classes and Annotations and provides a clean API to actually call those Functions. 
it's quite well documented as well.

Comment: I am not able to access the site given in the post. ie  Hibersap (http://hibersap.org/).

Comment: i just tried to access the url i mentioned in the answer ... it still works. probably a temporary glitch.